# Break each 4 months when axis x is numeric (number of the week) ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with some dates starting from 2000 to 2016 and some datas I want to plot. However, the dates are not equal if we compare them for two consecutive years : first the value of the dates might be different and second, I have sometimes one more or less value between two years.

Datas for the years 2000, 2001 and 2002 with `head` and `tail` :

```
      numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest         numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest        numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest
1: 2000-01-03        1    2000           1   1: 2001-01-01       13    2001           1  1: 2002-01-07       77    2002           1
2: 2000-01-10        0    2000           2   2: 2001-01-08       22    2001           2  2: 2002-01-14       95    2002           2
3: 2000-01-17        0    2000           3   3: 2001-01-15       21    2001           3  3: 2002-01-21       69    2002           3
4: 2000-01-24        0    2000           4   4: 2001-01-22       11    2001           4  4: 2002-01-28       91    2002           4
5: 2000-01-31        0    2000           5   5: 2001-01-29       24    2001           5  5: 2002-02-04       89    2002           5

      numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest       numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest       numWeek effectif numYear numWeektest
48: 2000-11-27       14    2000          48 49: 2001-12-03       53    2001          49 48: 2002-12-02      112    2002          48
49: 2000-12-04       14    2000          49 50: 2001-12-10       65    2001          50 49: 2002-12-09      171    2002          49
50: 2000-12-11       12    2000          50 51: 2001-12-17       66    2001          51 50: 2002-12-16      132    2002          50
51: 2000-12-18       13    2000          51 52: 2001-12-24       17    2001          52 51: 2002-12-23       35    2002          51
52: 2000-12-25        4    2000          52 53: 2001-12-31       28    2001          53 52: 2002-12-30       54    2002          52
```

`numWeektest` is the number of the week. You can see I have sometimes, `52` or `53` values for a year.

So what I did is to get the number of the week, plot it by group of years and I get this :

[image: x axis number of the week]

It works very well but I want to do is to break the axis x by 4 months but I can't do that since my x axis is `numeric` and not `Date`. I tried to change the x axis but then I get this :

[image: axis x is date]

So how should I do ?

Code :

```
test_p <-ggplot(test_c, aes(x = numWeek, y = effectif, group = numYear, colour = as.factor(numYear))) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  #scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0.5)) replace discrete or date according to the x axis values
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0.5))
```

EDIT :

What I would like to have is (it was modified with Paint) :

[image]

Datas :

```
structure(list(numWeek = structure(c(10959, 10966, 10973, 10980, 
10987, 10994, 11001, 11008, 11015, 11022, 11029, 11036, 11043, 
11050, 11057, 11064, 11071, 11078, 11085, 11092, 11099, 11106, 
11113, 11120, 11127, 11134, 11141, 11148, 11155, 11162, 11169, 
11176, 11183, 11190, 11197, 11204, 11211, 11218, 11225, 11232, 
11239, 11246, 11253, 11260, 11267, 11274, 11281, 11288, 11295, 
11302, 11309, 11316, 11323, 11330, 11337, 11344, 11351, 11358, 
11365, 11372, 11379, 11386, 11393, 11400, 11407, 11414, 11421, 
11428, 11435, 11442, 11449, 11456, 11463, 11470, 11477, 11484, 
11491, 11498, 11505, 11512, 11519, 11526, 11533, 11540, 11547, 
11554, 11561, 11568, 11575, 11582, 11589, 11596, 11603, 11610, 
11617, 11624, 11631, 11638, 11645, 11652, 11659, 11666, 11673, 
11680, 11687, 11694, 11701, 11708, 11715, 11722, 11729, 11736, 
11743, 11750, 11757, 11764, 11771, 11778, 11785, 11792, 11799, 
11806, 11813, 11820, 11827, 11834, 11841, 11848, 11855, 11862, 
11869, 11876, 11883, 11890, 11897, 11904, 11911, 11918, 11925, 
11932, 11939, 11946, 11953, 11960, 11967, 11974, 11981, 11988, 
11995, 12002, 12009, 12016, 12023, 12030, 12037, 12044, 12051
), class = "Date"), effectif = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 12, 6, 6, 7, 3, 0, 
15, 7, 2, 8, 12, 12, 7, 9, 14, 9, 22, 10, 17, 12, 14, 9, 14, 
14, 14, 12, 13, 4, 13, 22, 21, 11, 24, 20, 20, 20, 26, 23, 43, 
16, 30, 29, 20, 25, 35, 48, 35, 43, 35, 34, 26, 45, 68, 45, 44, 
49, 33, 35, 24, 27, 24, 36, 60, 51, 47, 39, 41, 58, 45, 42, 72, 
26, 67, 59, 63, 70, 53, 65, 66, 17, 28, 77, 95, 69, 91, 89, 84, 
77, 91, 80, 109, 92, 116, 87, 87, 87, 102, 91, 74, 90, 80, 96, 
53, 100, 101, 114, 90, 84, 77, 77, 74, 76, 25, 45, 33, 121, 121, 
89, 96, 121, 108, 131, 128, 108, 159, 126, 136, 135, 112, 171, 
132, 35, 54), numYear = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002), numWeektest = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-157L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000007a90788>, .Names = c("numWeek", 
"effectif", "numYear", "numWeektest"))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate breaking the x axis by 4 months, please?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Oh yeah what I would like is to have on the x axis a line for each 4 months so it will start for January then May then September instead of the number of the weeks

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I put the expected results if you want to see what I mean by breaking each 4 months

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
test_c$dateNew <- as.Date(paste("2001-",format(test_c$numWeek, format="%m-%d")), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

test_p <-ggplot(test_c, aes(x = dateNew, y = effectif, group = numYear, colour = as.factor(numYear))) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 months", date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

What I do is convert the dates to a common year so january through decemeber will show up on the x-axis only once (instead of jan - dec for each year). Then I just format the date every 4 months and use the month label.

Note that I am interpreting your "every 4 months" as april (04), august (08) and december (12).

**Edit:** For your jan/may/sept breaks you could replace the last line with:

```
 scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(c("2001-01-01","2001-05-01","2001-09-01")), date_labels = "%B")
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Simple trick but very clever, I didn't think about it. The little "problem" with your answer is that I would have liked to keep the values for each factor on the same x line, that's why I, at first, try with the number of the week to do that. I don't know if you get it but for example, the first value in blue is more on the right than the two others. But I don't know if it's possible to do such a thing. (if you have any idea, tell me). Anyway, thanks for your answer. :)